# How to setup an efficient badwidth management for home wifi

Tags: router, bandwidth, qos, internet-sharing, traffic-shaping

I plan to share our wifi between 4 roommates and occasional guests and mobile devices.
We consume mb differently so the bill will not split evenly.

I would like to setup something as follows:

- When all 4 users are connected using their main devices (computer), the bandwidth allocation is as follows:

  - User 1: 40MB/s, or 40%.
  - User 2: 20MB/s, or 20%.
  - User 3: 20MB/s, or 20%.
  - User 4: 10MB/s, or 10%.
  - Guests and mobile devices: 10MB/s, or 10%.
- **Important**: When not all users are connected, the bandwidth is reallocated relatively between the connected users.

I'm looking for a minimum-maintenance solution. For example, updating the router's whitelist with a guest's MAC address is not practical.

Comment: just to make sure: you want to throttle the wifi-usage, not the internet-usage?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I **do** want to throttle internet usage. But I guess if there's an active data transfer between two devices over wifi then it will slow down the internet. But if integrating wifi throttling with internet throttling is too complicated then let's stick to only throttling the internet usage.

Comment: well, your question-title mentions wifi, the question is tagged wifi*... that's why I wanted to know if the perceived focus on wifi was real or just perceived.

Comment: anyway: the magic keywords you want to use: "traffic shaping" and "quality of service". find routers with capabilities builtin. the more expensive ones have this feature. if you want to go the cheap router: http://openwrt.org -> http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/packet.scheduler/packet.scheduler